# How to create a new 'secure scratchpad' buffer?

Tags: buffers, security, scratch-buffer

I want to be able to create a new buffer (and a new window with which to interact with it) to work with secret or sensitive info, e.g. passwords.

Ideally, none of the contents of the buffer would persist after it's closed or discarded. It'd probably be best if the contents are discarded too even when the last window for the buffer is closed. If possible, it'd be best if any in-memory copies of the buffer are 'wiped' when it's closed as well.

[The gnupg.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3645) claims:

> The script turns off viminfo and swapfile to increase security.

So doing both seems necessary, tho perhaps not sufficient. What else should I do?

Comment: Maybe also ensuring that [`undofile`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27undofile%27) is off, although it's off by default. Also maybe setting [`buftype`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27buftype%27) to `nofile`. These are just some things that come to mind, but security is not my expertise.

Answer (score 1):

In this case i would

```
:new
:setlocal buftype=nofile
:setlocal bufhidden=hide
:setlocal noswapfile
```

`buftype=nofile` does not associate the buffer with a file.

`noswapfile` does not create a swapfile.

`bufhidden=hide` hides the buffer, when its windows is closed.

Vim discards the content in the buffer on exit without warning.

If you like to clear it before, you can use [`:bw`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:bwipeout) to wipe the buffer.

There also is a [plugin](https://vim.sourceforge.io/scripts/script.php?script_id=664) for that, however, I haven't tried this one.

I would also like to add, that I'm not a security expert, and there conceivably are a number of ways to access that information.

Comment: I would rather use `set bufhidden=wipe` and additionally to make sure `:setl noundofiles` and perhaps disable the modeline (however that would need to be done globally). Depending on what you want, you can also conceal parts of the text so that one does not immediately see what is on your screen.

Comment: How do you conceal parts of the text?

Comment: using either custom syntax rules or some `:matchadd()` calls.