# Is there a shorter way to start vim with scratch buffer?

Tags: startup, scratch-buffer

Often times I use vim as a scratchpad - I just want to throw some text in there, maybe copy it to the clipboard, or munge it a bit, but it's not really important to keep it around.

Most of the time I do `vim /tmp/foo.txt` or whatever, but this gets a bit annoying. I combined [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12230/5574) with some responses on a previous question of mine and came up with this solution:

```
vim +noswapfile +"set buftype=nofile" +"set bufhidden=hide"
```

Which actually works! But... it's a bit wordy.

Is there a shorter way to start vim with a scratch buffer (without using a plugin)?

Comment: Have you considered making that an alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `sh`/`bash` answer (even though the site is vi)

```
vtmp () {
  vim +noswapfile +"setlocal buftype=nofile" +"setlocal bufhidden=hide" "$@"
}
```

A vim answer:

Put this function in your vimrc or in a `plugin/` file:

```
function Scratch()
  setlocal noswapfile
  setlocal buftype=nofile
  setlocal bufhidden=hide
endfunction
```

And then call vim as `vim -c 'call Scratch()'`, or make a sh function similar to the above.

Comment: Might be more convenient to use a command over a function: `:command! S setlocal noswapfile buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide`; you can then call it with `vim +S`, and converting an existing buffer is just `:S` (can of course also use a longer command name, but just `:S` works well enough for me). Also, your shell command can be a wee bit shorter by combining the settings in one `:setlocal`.

Comment: @MartinTournoij good points. I’ll add alternatives later.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function, and then call said function from console when opening vim with the `-c` flag?

Answer (score 1):

There might be better approaches (e.g. alias to `vim +noswapfile +"set buftype=nofile" +"set bufhidden=hide"`) but you can also use `VimEnter` autocommand to set up initial things, for example:

```
func! ScratchBuffer() abort
    if bufname() == ''
        setl buftype=nofile
        setl bufhidden=hide
        setl noswapfile
    endif
endfunc

augroup vim_start | au!
    au VimEnter * call ScratchBuffer()
augroup end
```

I am not sure if check for an empty buffer name is enough but a quick test I did turned out ok for me.